# Replacing only certain instances of text within matlab character array

Tags: arrays, matlab, replace

I have a large character array in matlab: 'lineDataA' - containing many different numbers.

I would like to find and replace all instances of the number '6002' and replace with '0', apart from the very first instance.

```
lineData = replace(lineDataA, '6002', '0');
```

This replaces alls instances

And

```
where6002 = strfind(lineDataA, '6002');
```

Gives the position of all the instances. However I am not sure how to replaces all the instances except the first?

Many thanks for your help,

Rob

Comment: How is the input stored exactly? Is it a character vector, an array of size n-by-4? Cell array? String array? You might need to replace `6002` by `0000` and not just `0` to keep the dimensions consistent...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression with lookbehind to replace `'6002'` when preceded by `'6002'`:

```
result = regexprep(lineDataA, '(?<=6002.*)6002', '0');
```

However, this will also replace things like `60025` by `05`. Not sure if that's an issue for your specific case.

Comment: Thank you Luis, It seems to me however that this does not actually replace the instances of '6002', rather it just inserts a '0' at the specified position?

Comment: So... what's the difference between replacing '6002'  by '0' and inserting a '0'  where there was a '6002'? Maybe post an example with actual variables

Comment: If you have a row char array os string, maybe what you want is `regexprep(lineDataA, '(?<=6002.*)6002', '0')` (regular expression with lookbehind: replace `'6002'` if preceded by `'6002'`). But that will also catch numbers like `60025`

Comment: Apologies fro not being clear, the character array 'lineData' contains for example '1 23 44 msdd 6002 667 32 hg 55 6002 5555 6002 rrt' and I want it to read:  either '1 23 44 msdd 6002 667 32 hg 55 0 5555 0 rrt'  or '1 23 44 msdd 6002 667 32 hg 55 5555 rrt'

Comment: Please see edited answer. If you need to avoid replacing things like `'60025'` by `'05'` that's trickier